# Should I pigtail from the bundle of neutrals in order to get the needed neutral connection?

Tags: electrical, dimmer-switch

My new universal dimmer (legrand adorne) has no wires of its own.  It requires a neutral.  My neutral wires are bundled together and capped in the box.  Should I pigtail from that bundle in order to get my needed neutral connection?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Just make sure the connector you use, is rated for the number and size of wires you're connecting.